# Pandas to_sql insert only some columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science-model

I am new using pandas. 
I am asking about how to insert specific columns using to_sql.

This is my explanation.

I have a database with a table *datasiswa* with columns:

- id: as int, with autoincrement, as primary key
- name: string
- age: string

And I have an excel file with header name and age.

How to use to_sql to insert in fields name and age only, without ids.

[image]

Comment: Is hiding your entire path really necessary?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to fill a SQL Table entries from a Excel file, and this table should create IDs automatically.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte Hide because credential our server, yes i just want insert name and age, whitout ids, because id automatically generate by autoincrement.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to perform two steps:

1. You get ride of the id column in the pandas dataframe:

   ```
   df=df.drop(columns=['id'])
   ```
2. Add the `index=False` param: to the `.to_sql()` method:

   ```
   selected.to_sql('dataiswa', engine, index=False)
   ```

Comment: 'id' column is not in the dataframe, it's in the database